# How to get details CAM logs

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-automation-manager

Sometimes the logs tab is empty and the instance creations fails bringing it to error state. How can i debug what went wrong and where? I am using Bluemix GUI to copy paste the terraform template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for a failed deployment in Cloud Automation Manager (CAM) you will see an error message in the deployment's Log File tab.  However if you do not see anything on the Log File tab and did not receive an error message at time of deployment, first check the template formatting and then open a support ticket with IBM for further diagnosis.  You can following the instructions at this link for contacting support.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudAutomationManager/cam_ts.html#ts_cam

The internal logs for Cloud Automation Manager will be reviewed by IBM support to help diagnose the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The CAM traouble shooting documentation is available here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudAutomationManager/cam_ts.html#ts_cam

I see that there some known issues with CAM. You can go through the troubleshooting guide and see if your error is one of the known issues. If not - they have provided instruction on how to contact support. I suggest you contact their support and seek help in getting the logs.